# Notepad++ How do you modify SCI_WORDRIGHT? (not working)

Tags: notepad++

In the Shortcut mapper-->Scintilla commands I have tried to set SCI_WORDRIGHT to a few values, including Ctrl+J, Ctrl+Spacebar and Ctrl+Tab. None seam to work (I've tried restarting Np++).
I can set it back to Ctrl+Right and it goes back to normal. How can I get it to work?

Comment: You need to unmap the previous command mapped to the shortcut you want.  Each of the ones you listed that you tried are already in use.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Add button to create an alternative mapping rather than replacing the default, such as 
Ctrl+Shift+Right:

- Open SCI_WORDRIGHT
- Check the Shift checkbox
- Click the Add button